# Pig 0.13 ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/JobContextImpl

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Just installed Pig 0.13 and I am attempting to use it with Hadoop 1.1.2. (Pig documentation states Pig 0.13 is compatible with Hadoop 1.1.2). Per the Pig install instructions, I set $PIG_CLASSPATH 
to point at /etc/hadoop where core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, and mapred-site.xml are defined. Hadoop cluster is functional and works fine with non-Pig jobs. Based on the error descriptions below, I understand that Pig cannot find the JobContextImpl class it is looking for.

Based on the Hadoop 1.1.2 API documentation, I don't believe "task" is a sub-package of the "mapreduce" package. I have tried adding hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar directly to $PIG_CLASSPATH
and that did not work. (After looking at the contents of hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar, and the Hadoop 1.1.2 API documentation, I don't believe JobContextImpl is defined in the package Pig is attempting to load it from). How do I get Pig 0.13 to work with Hadoop 1.1.2?

=======Error follows as below=======

```
14/08/03 14:01:05 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
14/08/03 14:01:05 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE
14/08/03 14:01:05 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType
2014-08-03 14:01:05,959 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.13.0 (r1606446) compiled Jun 29 2014, 02:27:58
2014-08-03 14:01:05,959 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/hadoop/pig-0.13.0/bin/pig_1407088865958.log
2014-08-03 14:01:06,112 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://master.localdomain:8020/
2014-08-03 14:01:06,388 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: master.localdomain:8021
2014-08-03 14:01:06,440 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/JobContextImpl
Details at logfile: /home/hadoop/pig-0.13.0/bin/pig_1407088865958.log
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:643)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

===Contents of pig_1407088865958.log ===

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/JobContextImpl
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/task/JobContextImpl
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil.<clinit>(PigStatsUtil.java:68)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:79)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:510)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Did you compile pig for Hadoop 1.x ?

Comment: Downloaded the binaries and source. Nowhere in the documentation does it state that it needs to be recompiled. In fact the website for Pig 0.13.0 states that it is compatible with 1.1.2. In my searching for help I saw posts stating that it needs to be recompiled with a parameter that indicates version. The parameter values I saw were 23,24. I did not know how that parameter mapped to the version of hadoop that I am using 1.1.2. I hacked the bin/pig script to point to hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar. The script requires HADOOP_HOME be set (which is deprecated). Didn't want to use a deprecated variable.

Comment: Did this work for you? For me it still fails When I try pointing to the hadoop-core jar manually.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?

I am getting the same errors. Hadoop was already installed 1.2.1
and pig is versioned at 0.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Though it is unclear how well this works for everyone, it appears that the asker mentioned how he solved the problem:

> In my searching for help I saw posts stating that it needs to be
>   recompiled with a parameter that indicates version. The parameter
>   values I saw were 23,24. I did not know how that parameter mapped to
>   the version of hadoop that I am using 1.1.2. I hacked the bin/pig
>   script to point to hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar. The script requires
>   HADOOP_HOME be set (which is deprecated).